# Spring Interface Converter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, functional-programming

I have ClassA and ClassB that I want to convert to ClassC, but if I want to user the Spring converter:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.converter
Interface Converter<S,T>
Type Parameters:
S - the source type
T - the target type
```

I should create another classD, like

```
ClassD classD {
      ClassA classA;
      ClassB classB;
}
```

and then from classD to classC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documentation of Spring's [`Converter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) says :

> A converter converts a source object of type `S` to a target of type `T`

So `S` is a source type and `T` is a target type.

So if you want to convert `ClassA` to `ClassB` you will create `Converter<ClassA, ClassB>` implementation. You cannot convert two types into single type using `Converter` at once. You would have to create two converters to convert in this order for example `ClassA -> ClassB -> ClassC`.

Or create some wrapper type for `ClassA` and `ClassB` :

```
public class Wrapper {
    private ClassA a;
    private ClassB b;
}
```

and then create a Converter `Converter<Wrapper, ClassD>` implementation :

```
Converter<Wrapper, ClassC> converter = wrapper -> {
        //access wrapper
        wrapper.getA();
        wrapper.getB();
        return new ClassC();
};
```